# discord.py embed reaction in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to do a suggestion command. The command is working. The command send an embed into a specific channel named "suggestions". I want to add reactions to the embed (❌ and ✅). Now I need your help. I am not able to add reactions to the embed. This is my actual code, without adding reactions:

```py
@bot.command()
async def suggestion(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description= content.split('/')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x00ff40)
    channel = bot.get_channel(857413508224385054)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("your suggestion is send!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the embed in order to add reactions.

**Simply do:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def suggestion(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description= content.split('/')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x00ff40)
    channel = bot.get_channel(857413508224385054)
    test = await channel.send(embed=embed) # Define the message
    await test.add_reaction("✅") # Add reactions
    await test.add_reaction("❌")
    await ctx.send("your suggestion is send!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Another way could be to set up an **event** that listens for messages in the channel:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 857413508224385054: # Checks if the channel is correct
        await message.add_reaction("✅") # Adds the reaction to all new messages
        await message.add_reaction("❌")
```